# Finding the belonging value of given point on a grid of 3D histogram?

Tags: matlab, search, histogram, interpolation

I use 2D dataset like below,

```
37.0235000000000    18.4548000000000
28.4454000000000    15.7814000000000
34.6958000000000    20.9239000000000
26.0374000000000    17.1070000000000
27.1619000000000    17.6757000000000
28.4101000000000    15.9183000000000
33.7340000000000    17.1615000000000
34.7948000000000    18.2695000000000
34.5622000000000    19.3793000000000
36.2884000000000    18.4551000000000
26.1695000000000    16.8195000000000
26.2090000000000    14.2081000000000
26.0264000000000    21.8923000000000
35.8194000000000    18.4811000000000
```

to create a 3D histogram.

[image]

*How can I find the histogram value of a point on a grid?* For example, if `[34.7948000000000    18.2695000000000]` point is given, I would like to find the corresponding value of a histogram for a given point on the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code

```
point = feat_vec(i,:); // take the point given by the data set
X = centers{1}(1,:); // take center of the bins at one dimension
Y = centers{2}(1,:); // take center of the bins at other dim.  

distanceX = abs(X-point(1)); // find distance to all bin centers at one dimension 
distanceY = abs(Y-point(2)); // find distance to center points of other dimension

[~,indexX] = min(distanceX); // find the index of minimum distant center point
[~,indexY] = min(distanceY); // find the index of minimum distant center point for other dimension
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`interp2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) to accomplish that!

---

If `X` (1-D Vector, length *N*) and `Y` (1-D vector, length *M*) determine discrete coordinate on the axes where your histogram has defined values `Z` (matrix, size *M **x** N*). Getting value for one particular point with coordinates (`XI`, `YI`) could be done with:

```
% generate grid
[XM, YM] = meshgrid(X, Y);
% interpolate desired value
ZI = interp2(XM, YM, Z, XI, YI, 'spline')
```

In general, this kind of problem is **interpolation** problem. If you would want to get values for *multiple* points, you would have to generate grid for them in similar fashion done in code above. You could also use another interpolating method, for example `linear` (refer to linked documentation!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

> [N,C] = hist3(X,...) returns the positions of the bin centers in a
>       1-by-2 cell array of numeric vectors, and does not plot the histogram.

That being said, if you have a 2D point `x=[x1, x2]`, you are only to look up the closest points in `C`, and take the corresponding value in N.

In Matlab code:

```
[N, C] = hist3(data); % with your data format...
[~,indX] = min(abs(C{1}-x(1)));
[~,indY] = min(abs(C{2}-x(2)));
result = N(indX,indY);
```

done. (You can make it into your own function say `result = hist_val(data, x)`.)

---

EDIT:

I just saw, that my answer in essence is just a more detailed version of @Erogol's answer.